# How to produce a range with step n in bash? (generate a sequence of numbers with increments)

Tags: bash, range, iteration

The way to iterate over a range in bash is

```
for i in {0..10}; do echo $i; done
```

What would be the syntax for iterating over the sequence with a step? Say, I would like to get only even number in the above example.

Comment: Even numbers, multiply i by 2. :P

Comment: multiplication is rather ugly, I should say

Comment: @Omnifarious I would not be so sure. OS X still comes with 3.2, for example. I would say the C-style loop should be accepted.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I'd do

```
for i in `seq 0 2 10`; do echo $i; done
```

(though of course `seq 0 2 10` will produce the same output on its own).

Note that `seq` allows floating-point numbers (e.g., `seq .5 .25 3.5`) but bash's brace expansion only allows integers.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that the downvote was due to your answer being generic to 'sh', and not specific to 'bash'.  

The pure Bash approach {begin end step} performs just a little better.The older 'seq' method's handy on older or smaller-memory systems like busybox.

I did upvote both your and TheBonsai's answer. :)

Comment: Prefer $(...) to backquotes. Backquotes do not nest sanely.

Comment: seq 1000000 1000010 only does floats, actually - there's no way to make it do integers! Brace expansion works.

Comment: How could I save result(output) into a file?

Answer (score 160):

**Bash 4**'s brace expansion has a step feature:

```
for {0..10..2}; do
  ..
done
```

No matter if Bash 2/3 (C-style for loop, see answers above) or Bash 4, I would prefer anything over the 'seq' command.

Comment: and btw, do you know if bash4 is default on any major OS?

Comment: Bash4 still isn't mainstream, no. Why not seq? Well, let's say it with the words of the bot in the IRC channel #bash: "seq(1) is a highly nonstandard external command used to count to 10 in silly Linux howtos."

Comment: my understanding is that seq is a part of coreutils. what is non-standard about it? arguments? thanks for your help.

Comment: These arguments may or may not count for you: * there are enough systems without GNU coreutils (but Bash installed) * you create an unneeded external process * you rely on the idea that all 'seq' do what your 'seq' does * it's not standardized by the ISO

Comment: @becko If the step is stored in the variable `i`, then you can't do `for {0..10..${i}}` .. it fails.

Comment: Another reason: thats not as easy with seq: ``echo 0{1..9..2}``

Comment: Another reason: `seq 1000000 1000010` only can do floats (look at the manpage!). {1000000..1000010} works as expected.

Answer (score 103):

Pure Bash, without an extra process:

```
for (( COUNTER=0; COUNTER<=10; COUNTER+=2 )); do
    echo $COUNTER
done
```

Comment: +1 Because the step can be replaced by a variable too.

Comment: I think this is really what most people likely want -- a simple way to do a loop with a prescribed step value. It sounds simpler than all of the seq based answers, and is a clearer syntax than Bash4 brace expansion, and looks like it would allow for variables (I haven't tried that, but the syntax definitely suggests that).

Comment: Works in Bash 3, unlike @TheBonsai's answer.

Comment: It even resolves variable, ((i="$first" ; i<="$last" ; i+="$step")). Not so easy with curly braces and seq.

Comment: This is sometimes much faster than `{0..10..2}`-style, e.g. when the range is really large.

Answer (score 25):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 2 10)
do
   echo "skip by 2 value $i"
done
```

Comment: seq is a Linux command. This won't be available on Mac OS X or FreeBSD.

Comment: FWIW seq is available in my standard OS X Mavericks 10.9.1

Comment: I have try some other sintax, but that is the only is working for my on a little CentOS. @z - has saved my day :D

Answer (score 16):

## Use `seq` command:

```sh
$ seq 4
1
2
3
4

$ seq 2 5
2
3
4
5

$ seq 4 2 12
4
6
8
10
12

$ seq -w 4 2 12
04
06
08
10
12

$ seq -s, 4
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 5):

brace expansion {m..n..s} is more efficient than seq.
AND it allows a bit of output formatting:

```
$ echo {0000..0010..2}
0000 0002 0004 0006 0008 0010
```

which is useful if one numbers e.g. files and want's a sorted output of 'ls'.

Comment: Be aware that some programs may read 0010 as 8 (i.e. they read octal when there is a leading 0 because this is done in C).

Comment: This works to my surprise while running *GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)* . Apparently and somehow inconsistently the leading zero isn't considered to be an octal number indicator as in `echo $((020+001))` which prints `17`, where `echo {000..020..002}` prints `000 002 004 006 008 010 012 014 016 018 020`